# Inflating and accessing EditText values

Tags: android, android-inflate

I am inflating a TableRow which contains an EditText multiple times. I manage to retrieve the EditText and edit the setHint value before adding the row to the table. How can I tag each Editext so that I can later check each EditText value?(User input in each editText4). Is setTag the right way to go?

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

rowView = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablerow, null);
EditText editText = rowView.findViewById(R.id.edittext);


editText.setHint("Number " + Integer.toString(currentField));
```

How can I set and retrieve an Id or tag to each individual EditText?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are placing the TableRow into a TableLayout. If this is the case, you could use the ViewGroup method getChildAt(int position) inherited by TableLayout to get the TableRow at the specified position.